# Are DOM elements objects?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting the following in the developer console.

```
<img src="http://localhost/baazar_search/public/assets/uploads/images/logo/f5257d77-75c3-426b-867a-8dea600f7345.jpg" draggable="false" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 50px; height: 50px; -webkit-user-select: none; border: 0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; max-width: none; opacity: 1;">
```

The type of is of above is showing `OBJECT`. I want to apply method addClass() to above image element. How to convert this object to DOM element.

Script is-

```
    for (k = 0; k < offerCode.length; k++)
    {
        console.log(offerCode[k]);
        console.log(typeof offerCode[k]);
    }

var offerCode = $("#markerLayer").find("[src='" + requiredImage + "']");
```

Comment: When did you get is as `OBJECT` ? Where is your script ?

Comment: @Rayon check the edited post

Comment: DOM elements **are** objects.

Comment: @Barmar, Yes but all I wanted is to go through his JS code..Wanted to know about the api OP is using to select the element!

Comment: @AbhimanyuSingh, What is `offerCode` ? How do you get it ?

Comment: @Rayon My comment was directed at the OP, not you, since he seems to think there's something significant about `typeof` showing `object`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DOM elements **are** objects -- `typeof` doesn't distinguish between all the different types of objects.

`addClass()` is a method on a jQuery object, not a DOM element, so you need to convert the DOM element to jQuery. Use `$()` to do this.

```
$(offerCode[k]).addClass("some-class");
```

Or, since `offerCode` is a jQuery collection, you can use

```
offerCode.addClass("some-class");
```

This will add the class to all the elements in the collection.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar.. You are awesome :)

Answer (score 0):

use jQuery:

```
for (var k = 0; k < offerCode.length; k++)
{
    $(offerCode[k]).addClass("some-class");
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vwf1qyab/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery selector to choose that exact image.

```js
$('img[src="http://localhost/baazar_search/public/assets/uploads/images/logo/f5257d77-75c3-426b-867a-8dea600f7345.jpg"]').attr('class', 'img-class');
```

or

```js
$('*img[src="http://localhost/baazar_search/public/assets/uploads/images/logo/f5257d77-75c3-426b-867a-8dea600f7345.jpg"]').addClass('img-class');
```